# short в byte без потери данных

Tags: c#, .net

Я понимаю что типы разные не только по самому типу, диапазону, но и по их размеру, но есть ли безопасный способ привести тип `short` к типу `byte`? Это необходимо для отправки данных по сети через `TcpClient`. Или как обойти ограничение

```
NetworkStream.Write(byte[], int offset, int count)
```

У меня есть идеи с `BitConverter.GetBytes(short)` но не уверен что смогу обработать данные на сервере с таким конвертированием.

Comment: А в чем проблема на сервере с обратным конвертированием?

Comment: Не будут оформлять как ответ, если `byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((short) 1000); // { 232, 3 }` то обратная операция `short s = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, startIndex: 0); // 1000`

Comment: Проблема не в обратном преобразовании, а в затрате времени на преобразование.

Comment: В затрате времени? Это шутка такая?

Comment: @LLENN Преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех зол.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
short x = -1000;
byte a = (byte)(x >> 8);
byte b = (byte)(x & 255);
Console.WriteLine(a + " " + b); // 252 24
short z = (short)(a << 8 | b);
Console.WriteLine(z); // -1000
```